# How to get text between <a> </a> tags with regex

Tags: java, javascript, html, ajax, regex

I have this

```
<a align="center" href="http://google.com"><b>Google Link<b></b></a>
<a align="center" href="http://yahoo.com"><strong>Yahoo Link</strong></a>
```

I want this

```
<b>Google Link Yahoo Link</b>
```

If anyone know so please help me.

Comment: Why would you use a regex? Just have the HTML parsed into a DOM and modify that.

Comment: because i have a software and in software i can only insert regex

Comment: Don't use regex to parse HTML: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/315168 as you have perfectly good HTML parsers available

Comment: i have found this (?<=<\s*a[^>]*>)(?<anchorContent>[\s\S]*?)(?=<\s*/a>)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use either the [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533899%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) or [textContent](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Core/core.html#Node3-textContent) property of the A element as appropriate:

```
var theText = aElement.innerText || aElement.textContent;
```

All browsers in use support one or the other, some both.

If you want to replace the content of all links with plain text, you could do something like:

```
var link, links = document.links;
for (var i=0, iLen=links.length; i<iLen; i++) {
  link = links[i];
  link.innerHTML = link.innerText || link.textContent;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
​$('a')​.each​(function(){
    $(this).text();
});​
```

Comment: Since the OP wants to replace the text, I guess your version of the function would be: `$(this).html($(this).text());`